# How to find the first declaring method for a reference method

Tags: java, generics, reflection, inheritance, proxy

Suppose you have a generic interface and an implementation:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {

  void foo(T param);
}

public class MyImplementation<T> implements MyInterface<T> {

  void foo(T param) {

  }
}
```

These two types are framework types I provide. In the next step I want allow users to extend that interface as well as redeclare `foo(T param)` to maybe equip it with further annotations.

```
public interface MyExtendedInterface extends MyInterface<Bar> {

  @Override
  void foo(Bar param);

  // Further declared methods
}
```

I create an AOP proxy for the extended interface and intercept especially the calls to furtherly declared methods. As `foo(…)` is now redeclared in `MyExtendedInterface` I cannot execute it by simply invoking `MethodInvocation.proceed()` as the instance of `MyImplementation` only implements `MyInterface.foo(…)` and not `MyExtendedInterface.foo(…)`.

So is there a way to get access to the method that declared a method initially? Regarding this example is there a way to find out that `foo(Bar param)` was declared in `MyInterface` originally and get access to the accoriding `Method` instance?

I already tried to scan base class methods to match by name and parameter types but that doesn't work out as generics pop in and `MyImplementation.getMethod("foo", Bar.class)` obviously throws a `NoSuchMethodException`. I already know that `MyExtendedInterface` types `MyInterface` to `Bar`. So If I could create some kind of "typed view" on `MyImplementation` my math algorithm could work out actually.

Additional info:

I create the proxy for the `MyExtendedInterface` as follows:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setTarget(new MyImplementation());
factory.setInterfaces(new Class[] { MyExtendedInterface.class });
factory.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor(MyExtendedInterface.class));
```

The interceptor pretty much scans the methods and executes JPA queries for all methods declared in `MyExtendedInterface` but routes all method invocations of methods declared in `MyInterface` to the proxy target. This works as long as methods from `MyInterface` are not redeclared as the target then doesn't implement it anymore.

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation)
            throws Throwable {

    // handling of query methods
    // else

    invocation.proceed();
    // ^^ works if not redeclared but not if
  }
}
```

So what I would like to do instead of invocation.proceed() is detect the method that *originally declared the one being invoked* and invoke that on the target manually.

Comment: I have no response, but I think MyExtendedInterface.class.getMethod("foo", Bar.class) should be ok, with synthetic or bridge marker. Is that help you ?

Comment: I don't really get how this would help. I iterate over the declared methods of `MyExtendedInterface`. The problem is that I cannot cleanly match them against the ones declared in `MyImplementation.

Comment: what are you using for proxies? javassist? commons-proxy?

Comment: That's from Spring AOP, so simply JDK dynamic proxies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution I came up with: As I know the base class and it generics structure (what T means in this case) as well as `MyExtendedInterface` types `MyInterface` to `Bar` I can scan the base implementation for possible matches as follows (pseudocode):

```
for all methods {

   skip those with non matching name and parameters length;

   for all generic parametertypes {

     if typename = T then concrete type has to be Bar
     ...
   }
}
```

I don't need a generic solution in this case so that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The whole scenario seems strange. You can't apply AOP declared on `MyExtendedInterface` to `MyImplementation`, because it does not implement it.

Second, I don't understand why it matters which interface defines a method, since it is the implementation that the method is invoked on.

Apart from that, you can get all the methods declared by a certain class/interface by `getDeclaredMethods()`. Then you can iterate on them and find something that matches your criteria (name)

Comment: I can. I create the proxy programmatically and add an simple interceptor that intercepts *every* method call. Within this interceptor I decide where to route the actual method call to.

`getDeclaredMethods()` is an option but I have to make sure the redeclared method actually overrides one from `MyInterface. One could actually also declare a `foo(Foobar param)` which wouldn't override the actual method then. So it seems there's no way to find out whether a method overrides another method esp. with generics involved.

Comment: could you provide the code of the interceptor. I can't quite understand your scenario.

Comment: Added proxy creation code and interceptor to the original question.